# Get the expiration date on an Azure storage account-lvel SAS?

Tags: azure-storage

I'm looking for a way to find any expired or expiring SAS signatures on an Azure **storage account**.

Using C# I have examined all the public properties and methods of the CloudStorageAccount class, I have also looked at this class in ILSpy and Azure Resource explorer - just can't see a way to retrieve the SAS expiry date/time.

```
void Main()
{   
    CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new 
         StorageCredentials(GetName(), GetKey()), true);
    account.Dump();

    CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    foreach (CloudBlobContainer container in client.ListContainers())
    {
        var sabp = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
        var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sabp);
        Console.WriteLine(container.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(sas);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }   
}

internal string GetName() {return @"myaccountname";}
internal string GetKey() {return @"myaccountkey";}
```

The is no error but also no way (I can see) to get the account-level SAS.
*Note* I do not want any blob SAS but the SAS set against the container. 
Thanks

Comment: what's your purpose? just get the expired time of the sas token in your above code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if your account-level SAS is expired or expiring of , based on [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas#specifying-account-sas-parameters) , you can just check the `SignedExpiry` param. in SAS , its name is `se`.

Try the code below to get a account-level SAS with blob object read permission and has 1 day's lifetime:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("<storage  account name>", "<storage key>"), true);

        var accesspolicy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read,
            Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object
        };
        var accountSAS = account.GetSharedAccessSignature(accesspolicy);

        Console.WriteLine(accountSAS);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Result :

[image]

As you can see, the `se` param is there and indicates this sas will expire after 1 day.

So you can use this sas to access your blobs : 
[image]

Comment: Hello, Not seeing on how I can set at this setting for account-level SAS that are already created.  My object type is CloudStorageAccount but that does not expose anything called SignedExpiry or se.  Also, will be a number of SAS against this account so how to I get them all?        
 
 CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(GetName(), GetKey()), true);

Comment: Hi @Dave , I have updated my answer , pls have a check .

Comment: Hi @Stanley,  Thanks for the updated code example.  I modded it slightly to also use SharedAccessStartTime but I'm still not seeing how I can get multiple account-level SAS.  <br>  I've added three new SAS to this container today, they are as follows

Comment: **start = 2019-11-06  expires = 2019-11-07**
?sv=2019-02-02&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=r&se=2019-11-07T20:39:12Z&st=2019-11-06T12:37:12Z&  <br> <br>

**start = 2019-11-06  expires = 2019-11-08**
?sv=2019-02-02&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=r&se=2019-11-08T20:39:12Z&st=2019-11-06T12:37:12Z&  <br> <br>

**start = 2019-11-06  expires = 2019-11-09**
?sv=2019-02-02&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=r&se=2019-11-09T20:39:12Z&st=2019-11-06T12:37:12Z&  <br>    <br> and yet the code only returns one and it's not for any of these.

Comment: Hi, @Dave ,  I am not quite sure about multiple account-level SAS , can you tell me more about it ?Seems start time and expire time in SAS are all right in your case.

Comment: Hi @Stanley, the comment with the three "start =" was just to document that I had created three separate SAS with start dates.   The formatting did not quite come out as expected though:-(   Anyway, I posted this question to MS via the Azure portal and it appears you cannot query SAS expiration dates, you can record them whilst creating but not afterwards.  Thanks for your comments though.  Cheers